# Pygame Move Image Speed

Tags: python, object, pygame

I'm a newb when it comes to programming, but I'm learned a lot so far and I'm trying to make a very basic RPG.

I want to move my image object oPC with a mouse click.  I've been able to accomplish this with the code I'm sharing below, however, no matter where I click on the screen the image takes the same amount of steps/time to get there.  For instance, if I click a few inches away from the object it will gradually shift across the screen towards the target location just as fast as if I'd click right off the image.

I've been stuck trying to figure out a way to solve this issue for the last few days.  Is there someway to use time for movement as opposed to the steps I've used?

Thanks!

```
import pygame, sys
import oPC

pygame.init()

WINDOWSIZE = (1000, 800)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWSIZE))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

screen.fill(BLACK)
terrain = pygame.image.load("terrain.jpg").convert()
terrainRect = terrain.get_rect()
terrain = pygame.transform.scale(terrain, ((WINDOWSIZE)))
screen.blit(terrain, terrainRect)

oPC = oPC.Player()
oPC.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
n_steps = 80

while running == True:


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mlocX, mlocY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            while mlocX != oPC.rect.x and mlocY != oPC.rect.y:
                clock.tick(60)
                oPC.update(mlocX, mlocY, n_steps)
                if n_steps > 1:
                    screen.fill(BLACK)
                    screen.blit(terrain, terrainRect)
                    n_steps -= 1
                    oPC.draw(screen)
                    pygame.display.flip()

            n_steps = 80

pygame.quit()
#sys.exit()



    import pygame, sys

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("tipping over s0000.bmp").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.name = " "
        self.stats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #str, int, dex, health, mana
        self.admin = False # False = Member / True = Administrator

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (75, 75))
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))


    def update(self, mlocX, mlocY, n_steps):
        self.rect.x += (mlocX - self.rect.x) / n_steps
        self.rect.y += (mlocY - self.rect.y) / n_steps
```

Answer (score 1):

Your design has a few flaws.

You are calling `clock.tick()` only on the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event. It should be called on every frame.

Your bliting and display.update should also be done in the loop, not in the event queue.

The player update should also be called in the loop.

You scale your image each time you call draw. I think you may want to do that in the init method only. Since draw should be called repeatedly in the loop.

As for the step counter, I suggest to have a player state, and a step counter there. Something like this:

```
# for easier state access
def enum(*sequential, **named):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

player_states = enum('STATIONARY', 'MOVING')
STEPS = 30
def __init__(self):
    self.state = player_states.STATIONARY
    self.steps = 0
    self.dest = None
def move(self,mlocX,mlocY):
    if self.state != player_states.MOVING:
        self.state = player_state.MOVING
        self.steps = STEPS
        self.dest = (mlocX,mlocY)
def update(self):
    if self.steps != 0:
        self.rect.x += (self.dest[0] - self.rect.x) / STEPS
        self.rect.y += (self.dest[1] - self.rect.y) / STEPS
        self.steps -= 1
    else:
        self.state = player_states.STATIONARY
```

As for you question with steps, you can use physics and the famous `distance = velocity * time` equation.

The clock.tick() method returns the number of ms passed since the last call to tick().
If you pass this to the update method, you can than change the moving equations to:

```
def update(self,delta):
    self.rect.x += PLAYER_SPEED * direction * delta
```

Then pick PLAYER_SPEED to something that will suit you.